# ajax не обрабатывается ответ

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ответ приходит, но почему то Jquery его не обрабатывает!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form').submit(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/login.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    traditional: true,
    success: function(response) {
if (response == 'yes') {
    $("#oKmessage").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#form").hide(1000);
    window.location.reload(); 
} else if (response == 'no') {
    $("#nomessage").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#form").hide(1000);
} else 
    $("#emptymessage").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#form").hide(1000);
},
error: function(response) {
/* ошибка соединения с интернетом */
}
});
return false;   
})

});


<?php
require "../core.php";

if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
if ($_POST["username"] != '' or $_POST["password"] != '') {

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["username"]);
$password = hash('sha256', $_POST["password"]);
$check    = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT username, password FROM 
`players` WHERE `username`='$username' AND password='$password'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $autch = 'yes';
} else {
    $autch = 'no';
}
echo $auth;
} 

}

?>
```

Comment: У Вас в $.ajax два обработчика error. Текст SQL запроса в оригинальном скрипте тоже на новую строку переносится или Вы сделали так здесь для "удобочитаемости"? Смотрели в консоли ответ от сервера? Не могли бы Вы его привести здесь?

Comment: [Violation] 'load' handler took 1201ms

Answer (score 0):

В ajax нет передачи signin, потому как минимум не проходит проверка

```
if (isset($_POST["signin"])) {
```

Comment: сделал if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) { все равно не работает

Comment: @Артём если ссылку на php файл в браузере открыть он что показывает? Должен отдавать цифру 1, или ошибку (если вывод их не отключен)

Comment: [Violation] 'success' handler took 2633ms
storage.min.js:1 [Violation] 'success' handler took 1727ms
dl.metabar.ru/static/storage/js/storage.min.js:1 [Violation] 'success' handler took 2113ms

Comment: Ответ приходит но не обрабатывается